# GUI created by PyQt4 and executed in python doesnt open up

Tags: python, pyqt4

The GUI, a Dialog box just doesnt open up, no matter where I execute the python file. Im using Windows 10. It doesnt matter if ist executed in IDLE or the QGIS Python console, etc..

```
from __future__ import division
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic



qtCreatorFile = r"D:\tax_calc.ui" # Enter file here.



Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)



class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.calc_tax_button.clicked.connect(self.CalculateTax)

    def CalculateTax(self):
        price = int(self.price_box.toPlainText())
        tax = (self.tax_rate.value())
        total_price = price  + ((tax / 100) * price)
        total_price_string = "The total price with tax is: " + str(total_price)
        self.results_window.setText(total_price_string)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
window = MyWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

to

```
window = MyWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: it doesn't help! Ive been also using this script: (see above)

Comment: No other idea anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsulating your code's main section with a try clause, this way if it's an exception you'll be able to see it

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = MyApp()
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))
```